# Code Igniter email attachment appears but content is empty

Tags: html-email, email-attachments, codeigniter-3

I'm using Code Igniter's email class to add an attachment to an email.
The attachment would appear however it's contents was always empty. I was able to verify (in the email source) that the attachment content is actually present (base64 encoded).

On the SO question linked, Torsten Arendrup answer was the solution which worked. I'm hoping to get some clarification as to why it works.
[Codeigniter send email with attach file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416585/codeigniter-send-email-with-attach-file)

In summary it seems that adding a new line after the 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: '(immediately before the attachment content is specified) fixes.
Is it simply that the email source is not formatted properly and bumping the content to the next line fixes this? Or is this a hack which actually does something else?

Thanks